# Entity Service VS super.find() VS Query Engine API, what is the differences?

Tags: node.js, strapi

I'm trying developer an ecommerce API and I have a question:

What's the difference between the `super.find()` and a `strapi.entityService`?

I have a product controller and I changed the find controller:

### products/controller/products.js

```
const { createCoreController } = require("@strapi/strapi").factories;

module.exports = createCoreController("api::product.product", ({ strapi }) => ({
  async find(ctx){

    const data = await super.find(ctx);

    ...
    //const data = await strapi.entityService.findMany("api::product.product");

    return data
}
```

Inside the function has a super.find and then has returning a specific structure of JSON, like this:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 8,
            "attributes": {
                "name": "Fiat Marea 20V ",
                "sku": "FT550",
                "description": "<p>Apenas uma descrição de teste Produto único topzeira&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p><strong>Altura</strong>: 12&nbsp;</p><p><strong>Largura</strong>: 12&nbsp;</p><p><strong>Produnfidade</strong>: 12</p>",
                "price": 19900,
                "status": true,
                "createdAt": "2022-12-02T22:23:47.483Z",
                "updatedAt": "2023-01-05T12:31:08.461Z",
                "quantity": 2,
                "price_discount": null,
                "publishedAt": "2023-01-05T12:14:25.342Z"
            }
        }
    ],
    "meta": {
        "pagination": {
            "page": 1,
            "pageSize": 25,
            "pageCount": 1,
            "total": 1
        }
    }
}
```

The structure of products startes with you id and your attributes but... If I use the `await strapi.entityService.findMany("api::product.product")` I has this return:

```
[
    {
        "id": 8,
        "name": "Fiat Marea 20V ",
        "sku": "FT550",
        "description": "<p>Apenas uma descrição de teste Produto único topzeira&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p><strong>Altura</strong>: 12&nbsp;</p><p><strong>Largura</strong>: 12&nbsp;</p><p><strong>Produnfidade</strong>: 12</p>",
        "price": 19900,
        "status": true,
        "createdAt": "2022-12-02T22:23:47.483Z",
        "updatedAt": "2023-01-05T12:31:08.461Z",
        "quantity": 2,
        "price_discount": null,
        "publishedAt": "2023-01-05T12:14:25.342Z"
    }
]
```

The structures of return is different, but why? how I can receive the same structure of `super.find()` using the `strapi.entityService` or `strapi.query`?

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

`super.find()` is a wrapping function that has built in `pagination`, `sanitizeEntity` and `transformResponse`.

strapi.EntityService is recommended API to be used in custom controllers and services, it's a higher level API that also handles components and dynamic zones.
strapi.db.query is lower level API, that gives unrestricted internal access to the database layer.

[reference](https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/developer-resources/database-apis-reference/query-engine-api.html)

To make it more easy, you can think about this as `entityService` is for creating and updating data, `db.query` is for finding and filtering data.

So, how to receive response in same data structure as super find:

```js
  async find(ctx) {
    const { query } = ctx;

    const entity = await strapi.entityService.findMany("api::test.test", query);
    const sanitizedEntity = await this.sanitizeOutput(entity, ctx);

    return this.transformResponse(sanitizedEntity);
  },
```

with simple pagination:

```js
async find(ctx) {
    let { query } = ctx;
    query.offset = query.offset ?? 0;
    query.limit = query.limit ?? 20;

    const entity = await strapi.entityService.findMany("api::test.test", query);
    const sanitizedEntity = await this.sanitizeOutput(entity, ctx);

    let { data, meta } = this.transformResponse(sanitizedEntity);

    return {
      data,
      meta: {
        total: await strapi.db.query("api::test.test").count(query),
        offset: query.offset,
        limit: query.limit,
      },
    };
  },
```